# Obtaining FastLink credentials for use in private zone

Tags: yodlee

I just received Cobrand ID, Application ID, Cobrand Username, and Cobrand password for use in my application's private zone. I am able to connect to the Yodlee service and obtain a Cobrand Token.

Prior to this I had been using the Yodlee evaluation environment and FastLink sandbox credentials as described in the [FastLink Integration](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide) guide.

Now that I'm using a private zone do I need new FastLink credentials specific to my application? If so, where I can get them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use different details to access Fastlink.
Please reach out to Yodlee support team to get details specifically to your environment. You can contact them over here- YI-Support@yodlee.com .